# How to make two vocabularies works as section and category for article?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

So basically i want terms from first vocabulary to work as sections that users can add (movies, for example), and terms from second vocabulary to be fixed amount of categories (like actors, info, screenshots etc), that users can only choose from.

I already made two fields with both vocabularies, but they works separate (*site.com/section* and *site.com/category*). Obviously, i want path to look like *site.com/section/category*. Tried Pathauto, but it works in a different way and can't do such things.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use views with arguments to create this pages.

you should create links manually with `l('title', "/{$vocab1_term}/{$vocab2_term}");` in your .tpl.php files associated with this views

Answer (score 0):

[check this](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/how-to-create-url-aliases-in-drupal-without-path-module) alternative way to custom urls like Pathauto make: http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/how-to-create-url-aliases-in-drupal-without-path-module, you can custom your urls according your needs (but according the documentation, you must be careful with your customization to not lost performance)